# How to know if render is complete before saving the canvas as image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to load canvas from json. change its image content using `setSrc` and render the canvas and save the canvas as image. i am trying to save the canvas as image after the render is complete but it is saving the old canvas not the updated canvas

right now i am using  setTimeout(save, 100);  before saving the canvas but is it the right way to do it... ?

my code

```
        function changeSrc(){
        canvas.clear();
    canvas.loadFromJSON(JSON.parse(json_data), function(obj) {
      canvas.renderAll();
       console.log(' this is a callback. invoked when canvas is loaded!xxx ');

      canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
    //    console.log(obj.name);

          if (obj.name == 'pro') {
                  var current_width = obj.width;
                  var current_height = obj.height;
                  obj.setSrc(url, function(obj1) {
                    obj1.set({
                      width: current_width,
                      height: current_height,
                      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'

                    })
                    canvas.renderAll();
                  });
                }

          if (obj.name == 'name') {
              var current_width = obj.width;
              var current_height = obj.height;
              obj.set({
                  width: current_width,
                  height: current_height,
                });
              obj.set({text :"i"+i});
                canvas.renderAll();
            }

      });
    });  

      setTimeout(save, 100);     


                 }



 function save(){
         $("#tcanvas").get(0).toBlob(function(blob){
                saveAs(blob, "myIMG.png");
            });
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

have you try this?

```
setTimeout(save, 100);
```

instead of

```
save();
```

Comment: one more thing i want to run the whole thing in a loop imagine there is an array of 100 different images. so it will loop 100 time and in each iteration it will replace the image source and save as image file. i tried running it in loop i download 100 image file but all with same image.

Comment: all of the same image is the last image?may be you should try let i not var i

Comment: i have updated my code with the loop... can you check it.... i did not run test on image but on text object...  so all the image had last text

Comment: i guess save function should be called everytime?does that make sense?

Comment: yes it does make sense... and i am calling save function within for loop... it is generating 30 images all with same text... all the images should have same image as expected but text should be changing...

Comment: is there any other way to know if the render is complete before saving the image....  i have updated the question.... please help

Comment: got a demo?i didn't know much about fabricjs.if you got a demo,i will try again.it is hard to test remotely